# Превью матча или превью к матчу?

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика

Как правильно употреблять "превью" - с предлогом или без?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Слово "превью" пока не фиксируется известными словарями, поэтому говорить о кодифицированных правилах его употребления несколько преждевременно, можно только прогнозировать.

Мне лично употребление без предлога в родительном падеже кажется вполне правильным, хотя бы по аналогии. Превью - это обозрение, обозрение матча. Ведь это . У предлога нет такого значения. С предлогом это было бы что-то типа "пирожок к чаю", а не сам чай.

Я за ***"превью матча"***. По факту именно этот вариант, насколько могу судить, сейчас явно лидирует. Можно предположить, что

Answer (score 3):

Если исходить из английского значения слова (*предварительный просмотр* чего-либо, обычно краткий, фрагментами), то по отношению к какой-либо передаче или грядущему изданию на диске и т.п. правильно **без предлога** в родительном падеже  - иначе выйдет конструкция, похожая на "список к участникам". По отношению к матчу, который ещё не состоялся, вряд ли в исходном смысле можно это слово употребить. Думаю, что можно лишь в случае рекламы диска с записью уже состоявшегося матча. Если же это материалы не из съёмок матча (интервью в преддверии матча и т. п.), то это что-то вроде развёрнутого *анонса* передачи о матче или самого матча.

**P.S.** (Спасибо Morkovkin за комментарий) Если обратиться к практике английской футбольной лиги, то "превью" используется как термин для такого анонса (презентации) и имеет смысл предварительной информации (All the team news ahead of the big games: http://www.theguardian.com/football/series/match-previews ) Сюда может входить информация о положении команд перед матчем, планируемая расстановка игроков на поле (в виде графики), данные о времени и месте проведения матча, времени прямой трансляции и т. п. То есть, в таком применении слово обозначает уже не "предпросмотр" заснятого матча, а предварительный взгляд на него, каким он "видится". По-видимому, в таком терминологическом значении слова не так важна его этимология или его английские грамматические связи (game preview формально соответствует родит. падежу), и допустимы оба варианта: **превью матча** (в значении "презентация матча") или **превью к матчу** (в значении "предварительная информация к предстоящему матчу").

Comment: Можно, вполне. В английском среди прочих значений есть не просто  предварительный просмотр, то, что делается перед просмотром. Да собственно сами англичане охотно это "превью" пользуют именно перед матчем.

Comment: Спасибо, что обратили на это внимание. Действительно, в применении к футбольным матчам это термин для доматчевой презентации. Подумаю, как изменить ответ.